# Switching from NHibernate to Massive or Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, massive

I understand the basic principles of the micro orm systems like massive and dapper, however i'm struggling with understanding how it's possible to model a table with relationships.

ie:

Category 1---M Product

In my NHibernate, or Linq2SQL solutions, Category has a List property.  There doesn't seem to be any examples of how this kind of relationship can be modelled.  Particularly in linq where we might select on a category where there are products with specific names.

Comment: In the case of dapper, the project home page gives examples of multi-mapping (basically, using a wide single result rest) and multiple result sets to do this. Have you tried these? http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: also, be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/info ... if you notice any information is missing there, edit headings in and I will fill the blanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of shifting from any traditional ORM. I insist that you must watch this [video](http://ndc2011.macsimum.no/mp4/Day2%20Thursday/Track1%201140-1240.mp4) posted by Rob Conery.

And the concern you showed in question about Domain Objects having another collection of domain objects as its property. It will not be an issue. Just a thing is this time you are putting values of that domain objected by your self.

Like here

```
Class Person
{
   public String FirstName{get;set;}
   public String LastName {get;set;}
   public IEnumarable<Address> {get;set;}
}

Class Address
{
   public String Address1 {get;set;}
   public String Address2 {get;set;}
}

Dynamic personData = new DynamicModel("connectionString","TableName","PrimaryKey");

var resultPerson = personData.All(where: "where condition") 
or 
var resultPerson = personData.Query("Join query will be here")

//Map resultPerson with PersonObject and return Person
//Still this will be faster than EF as per benchmark shown on Dapper page
```

I hope this will give your answer. If you need working code please let me know.

Comment: In that video Conery brags so much about how he became a developer and ... better if he just go to the point

Comment: @antew I personally like history part. Still there are lot talked about MicroORM if you like I can share links where things are up to the points...

Comment: Video link is dead. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'splitOn'. See for an example http://www.tritac.com/bp-24-dapper-net-by-example